# Parameter pack template metaprogramming depth first search

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have a parameter class like so:

```
template <class KEY, class VALUE>
class parameter
{
   VALUE v;
   ...
};
```

And I have a parameter pack class:

```
template <class... ELEMENTS>
class parameter_pack 
{
  std::tuple<ELEMENTS...> elems;
};
```

`parameter_packs` contain a number of `parameters` and/or `parameter_packs`.

I want a function (or method) like the following:

```
template <class KEY_TO_GET, class PARAMETER_PACK>
... get_value(const PARAMETER_PACK& p) { ... }
```

that does a depth first traversal for the first `parameter` that has the `KEY` value and returns its value. Of course this should be done at compile time, and should have constant runtime. Note `KEY` here is just a empty class, it is never created or used.

I'd like to be able to do this from the left or from the right.

The idea being you can have a set of default parameters which you can save to a variable and override before passing them to functions. I don't think boost::parameter allows saving (due to references to temporaries), and I believe it gives errors when you double up on a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I might have got it wrong, but isn't it something similar to the code below what you are looking for?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class nill
{

};

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE, VALUE v>
class parameter
{
    public:
        typedef KEY key_type;
        typedef VALUE value_type;
        static constexpr VALUE value = v;
};

template<typename ...>
class parameter_pack
{
};

template<typename KEY, typename P>
class get_param;

template<typename KEY, typename H, typename ...TAIL>
class get_param<KEY, parameter_pack<H, TAIL...>>
{
    private:
        typedef typename get_param<KEY, H>::type result;

    public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<result, nill>::value,
                typename get_param<KEY, parameter_pack<TAIL...>>::type, result>::type
                type;
};

template<typename KEY>
class get_param<KEY, parameter_pack<>>
{
    public:
        typedef nill type;
};

template<typename KEY, typename K, typename V, V v>
class get_param<KEY, parameter<K, V, v>>
{
    public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<K, KEY>::value,
                parameter<K, V, v> , nill>::type type;
};

template<unsigned T>
class tag
{
};

int main()
{
    typedef parameter_pack
            <
                parameter_pack
                <
                    parameter<tag<0>, int, 0>
                >,
                parameter_pack
                <
                    parameter<tag<4>, int, 42>,
                    parameter<tag<2>, int, 1>,
                    parameter_pack
                    <
                        parameter<tag<3>, int, 100>,
                        parameter<tag<4>, int, 5>,
                        parameter<tag<0>, int, 33>,
                        parameter<tag<2>, int, 666>
                    >
                >,
                parameter<tag<1>, int, -1>
            > pack;

    typedef typename get_param<tag<4> , pack>::type param;

    std::cout << param::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
42
```

Compiled by GCC 4.6

### **EDITED TO ALLOW RUN TIME VALUE MODIFICATION:**

For run time modification of valuess just modify the parameter class to the following:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class parameter
{
    public:
        typedef KEY key_type;
        typedef VALUE value_type;
        static VALUE value;
};

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
VALUE parameter<KEY, VALUE>::value;
```

which does not have a constant value member anymore.

Note that the value is a static variable tough, which means changing the value of one entry with a particular key changes the values of all the other entries. To overcome this problem, one may simply modify the "tagging system" so that two tags of different types may be considered the same key and then allowing the user to specify which meta function get_param should use to corectly identify the desired key (instead of always using std::is_same).
So the complete example which now allows run time modification of values is presented below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class nill
{

};

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class parameter
{
    public:
        typedef KEY key_type;
        typedef VALUE value_type;
        static VALUE value;
};

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
VALUE parameter<KEY, VALUE>::value;

template<typename ...>
class parameter_pack
{
};

template<template<typename> class MF, typename P>
class get_param;

template<template<typename> class MF, typename H, typename ...TAIL>
class get_param<MF, parameter_pack<H, TAIL...>>
{
    private:
        typedef typename get_param<MF, H>::type result;

    public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<result, nill>::value,
                typename get_param<MF, parameter_pack<TAIL...>>::type, result>::type
                type;
};

template<template<typename> class MF>
class get_param<MF, parameter_pack<>>
{
    public:
        typedef nill type;
};

template<template<typename> class MF, typename K, typename V>
class get_param<MF, parameter<K, V>>
{
    public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<MF<K>::value,
                parameter<K, V> , nill>::type type;
};

template<unsigned T, unsigned U = 0>
class tag
{
};

template<typename K1, typename K2>
class compare_tag;

template<unsigned T1, unsigned U1, unsigned T2, unsigned U2>
class compare_tag<tag<T1, U1>, tag<T2, U2>>
{
    public:
        static constexpr bool value = T1 == T2;
};

template<typename T>
class find4 : public compare_tag<T, tag<4>>
{};

template<typename T>
class find2 : public compare_tag<T, tag<2>>
{};

template<typename T>
class find1 : public compare_tag<T, tag<1>>
{};

int main()
{
    typedef parameter_pack
            <
                parameter_pack
                <
                    parameter<tag<0, 0>, int>
                >,
                parameter_pack
                <
                    parameter<tag<4, 0>, int>,
                    parameter<tag<2, 0>, int>,
                    parameter_pack
                    <
                        parameter<tag<3, 0>, int>,
                        parameter<tag<4, 1>, int>,
                        parameter<tag<0, 1>, int>,
                        parameter<tag<2, 1>, int>
                    >
                >,
                parameter<tag<1, 0>, int>
            > pack;

    std::cin >> get_param<find4, pack>::type::value;
    std::cin >> get_param<find2, pack>::type::value;
    std::cin >> get_param<find1, pack>::type::value;

    std::cout << get_param<find4, pack>::type::value << '\n';
    std::cout << get_param<find2, pack>::type::value << '\n';
    std::cout << get_param<find1, pack>::type::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
42
666
0
42
666
0
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I want, but the values should be setable at runtime, not just compile time.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ideone.com/0IsQU) is what I have so far. I can locate the proper `parameter`, I can `std::get` my way to it by hand, but it seems that at this hour I can't write the final wrapper that automatically does it for me for the life of me.

A proper solution should probably use Boost.MPL so as to not reinvent common techniques (e.g. sequences & `push_back`). It could also benefit from some lazy instantiations, because right now my solution touches every node.

Comment: You sir are positively insane -- `double***` ;-) Good luck!

Comment: @Kerrek Well I needed a type different from `double`, so naturally I used `double*`. You can see how it went from there.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a long time ago, but I ran in a similar problem, so I give may way to solve it (needs C++17 for std::apply, but may certainly be adapted for pure c++11) (live on https://godbolt.org/z/fxrPWY3Kh )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <class KEY, class VALUE>
struct parameter { VALUE v; };

template <class... ELEMENTS>
struct parameter_pack { std::tuple<ELEMENTS...> elems; };

struct key1; struct key2; struct key3; struct key4; struct key5;

// Next creates a tree of parameters, leaves are parameters,
// nodes are parameter_packs
using P1 = parameter<key1, int>;
using P2 = parameter<key2, float>;
using P3 = parameter<key3, std::string>;
using P4 = parameter<key4, const char *>;
using P5 = parameter<key5, std::tuple<int, float, bool>>;
using PP1 = parameter_pack<P1, P2>;
using PP2 = parameter_pack<PP1, P3, P4>;
using PP3 = parameter_pack<PP2, P5>;


// Try to match the first parameter.
// If it matchs, returns it, if not remove it from the list and
// call get again on the remaining
template <class Key, class SomeKey, class Val, class...Ps>
auto &get(parameter<SomeKey, Val>& p, Ps&...ps) {
       if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Key, SomeKey>) {
           return p;
       } else {
           return get<Key>(ps...);
       }
}

// Replace the first parameter_pack by its elements
// And recall get on the result.
template <class Key, class... P, class...Ps>
auto &get(parameter_pack<P...>&p, Ps&...ps) {
    return std::apply([&ps...] (auto&...p_)-> auto & { return get<Key>(p_..., ps...); }, p.elems);
}

int main() {
    PP3 pp;
    get<key1>(pp).v = 1;
    get<key2>(pp).v = 1.23456789;
    get<key3>(pp).v = std::string{"Hello World!"};
    get<key4>(pp).v = "litteral string";
    get<key5>(pp).v = std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, true);

    std::cout << get<key1>(pp).v << '\n'
              << get<key2>(pp).v << '\n'
              << get<key3>(pp).v << '\n'
              << get<key4>(pp).v << '\n';
   std::apply([&] (auto&...t) { std::cout << ( (std::to_string(t) + ' ') +...) << '\n'; }, get<key5>(pp).v);

}
```

Hope it can be useful to someone.